# show notification message on top of all windows

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to write windows service which listens for commands and if it receives one, it should show notification message. Now, problem is, I'd like to show the message in an unobtrusive way, meaning if user is platying game which opened in full-screen mode - I'd rather want the notification to be shown on top and then hidden, without changing mouse/keyboard focus, e.t.c. I have tried display ordinary message (`MessageBox.Show()`) but it doesn't work as expected - message is shown however main app is minimized.

Will appreciate any help on this or just links on possible ways of implemetation.

Answer (score 0):

You should split your application in to two parts: Windows Service and GUI application as stated [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/94c516ea-d9ca-45a9-9f49-518f9c46334f/can-i-toast-an-interactive-notification-from-windows-service?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues)

After that you can use [Toast Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts) sent from your GUI part

[Here](https://www.michaelcrump.net/pop-toast-notification-in-wpf/) is information how to use Toast Notifications from Windows Application

Comment: Should work in Windows8+, WinServer 2016+, however is this possible in Win XP/Vista/7?

Comment: no. You can also try to use https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1073989/WPF-Toast-Notification